# Отправка почтового сообщения с помощью php (и не только php)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, email

Искал в интернете и нашел https://webformyself.com/php-otpravka-elektronnoj-pochty-cherez-php/ , https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php и https://habr.com/ru/post/444744/ . Но как я понял это устаревший метод. Какие есть другие способы отправки почтового сообщения (хотелось бы знать весь список)?

Comment: [phpmailer](https://codernotes.ru/articles/php/otpravka-pisem-s-pomoshhyu-phpmailer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки почты необходимо реализовать smtp-клиент. Узнать об этом можно, задав себе (и гуглу) правильный вопрос: "что такое [электронная почта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0) и как она работает". Хороший разработчик не верит в волшебство и постоянно задаёт себе такие вопросы.

Почитав о протоколе, вы заметите, что реализация такого клиента не самое простое занятие. Наверняка есть уже готовые реализации.

Первое, что гуглиться по запросу "php smtp client" -- функция [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php). Зайдя на страницу официальной документации php (предпочитайте официальную документацию статьям в блогах начинающих программистов и ответам на stackoverflow) вы не обнаружите информации, что функция mail устарела. Она вполне актуальна. Однако, вас может не устроить её интерфейс (он действительно неудобный).

Можно продолжить исследовать выдачу гугла, а можно немного срезать путь, отправившись сразу в репозиторий современных php-пакетов (библиотек) [packagist](https://packagist.org/?query=mail) (если вы ещё не знакомы с composer, самое время познакомится). Тада! Вот он список. В нём есть сведения о количестве скачиваний и звёзд, что позволит сделать вам правильный выбор. Обратите внимание, что поиск в packagist ищет по описанию составленному самими разработчиками, экспериментируйте с ключевыми словами (например, справедливо предложенный вам в комментариях phpmailer не находится по "mail", "mailer", "smtp client", но находится по "email").

Резюме

- Исследуйте проблему начиная с основ. Вы можете не разбираться в тонкостях протоколов, но должны понимать, как работает то, что вы делаете.
- Всегда сперва ищите ответ на php.net, внимательно изучайте документацию.
- Используйте packagist для поиска актуальных библиотек (по крайней мере до тех пор, пока в мире php не появится что-нибудь получше).